# Powering 24 V and 12 V device simultaneously from two 12 V batteries

Tags: batteries, transformer, buck, wiring

I have two devices which need to be battery-powered (remote area, no grid power available). One device requires 24 V, the other requires 12 V. Both are very low amperage (~50 mA).

Can I use my two 12 V batteries in both series and parallel to provide 12 V to one device, and 24 V to the other?

Alternatively, I know I could use a step-up or a step-down transformer, but at least one of the devices monitors and reports battery voltage (maybe both, not sure yet), which I would lose with a stabilized voltage output. If for example I have to use a step down converter to go from ~24v > ~12v, is there a type of transformer which simply divides the input voltage in half, instead of always producing a stable 12V output? If so, what is it called? And is it more efficient to step up, or step down in this case?

Edited for clarity: I prefer not to run the 12 V device off a single battery, because I'd like the batteries to drain at the same rate.

Here is a simple drawing showing what I'd like to do:

[image]

Comment: If the 12 V device doesn't require as much power, you can just power it off one of the batteries. If it does need a lot of power, doing that will discharge one battery a lot faster than the other though, which isn't recommended.

Comment: Don't connect them like you've drawn; you are shorting out both batteries.  The solution depends on your loads: do they require constant 12V/24V or are they fine with normal battery voltage variation (13.6 to ~9V)?  The device that monitors battery voltage will probably be fine but the other may not be.  If they are, you can hook up both in series for the 24V one and power the 12V load off of **only one** of the batteries.

Comment: Thanks folks. I should have specified that it's important to me to draw equally off of both batteries.

Comment: That’s not possible without power electronics. You need a 24 -> 12 V buck converter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect them as shown in your drawing. To draw equally from the pair you will need a dc-dc buck converter as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAHrES.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: All the buck converters I've found put out a consistent 12V all the time as long as input voltage is between ~18v and ~30v. Is there a type of buck converter which will just divide the source voltage by half? I'd like my 12v device to see the actual battery voltage (or a linear representation of it anyway).. so if my 24v source is actually 26.2v, I'd like to get 13.1v output.

Comment: That should be attainable. I don't have a recommendation. Maybe some one else here can chime in.

Comment: @DannyF You can probably do something with a controller that features a tracking soft-start. That sort of feature is usually meant to control startup conditions, but it should be possible to use in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your generally stuck with the buck converter solution, otherwise yo end up with the grounded battery going flat and the 24V side battery overcharging, leading to 2 dead batteries in rather short order (enough moving truck owners try the same for radios..)

If your device that monitors battery voltage has a separate input for it, then you can have a divider just for that, while running the device off the buck converter (Based on my assumption its a device that monitors ignition voltage)

e.g. many ignition inputs on the kind of device I suspect it is, is about 100K load, so you can compensate the divider for the rather small range of voltage you actually want to know about

There is an alternative but its less common, a balance charger for the middle battery, they are not that cheap, and rely on your device being quite low load
https://www.outbackmarine.com.au/battery-balancer-victron-bba000100100